# java me: How to clear a file

Tags: file, java-me

How to clear a file in J2ME so that it becomes empty (no content)?
All output streams (`OutputStream, DataOutputStream, PrintStream...`)
can only `write()` and add the content to the file while I see no way to delete a byte/bytes in a file.
I use Netbeams 7.0.1
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call your **write()** method like this:

```
.write((new String()).getBytes());
```

This will make your file empty.

---

You can also delete your file and create a new one. This will also results into an empty file having the same file name.